# Azure Worker Role Cycling after VIP Swap

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm face with a problem. Azure Worker Role become Cycling after I swap VIP and it can't become healthy. There are no errors in Windows Azure logs. And PerfMon errors in Application logs.

How can I get rid of this problem?

UPD1:

I do some investigation and there are updates. WorkerRole fail in WorkerRole.cs with exception and then going to infinite recycling. I running Background Thread in OnRun method and there are Queue Handler. May be some of Queue handle exception that couldn't catch by try-catch.

Comment: Enable intellitrace to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. It's a stack overflow exception, that crash role.